# Redirect request from IIS to apache with virtual host without change the URL

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, iis, redirect

i have a bunch of apache servers behind a IIS, each server have one site running and the subdomain redirect from IIS to Apache is working fine with URL rewriter + ARR, like below:

```
                 -----
a.company.com >> |IIS| >> apache_server_a (10.0.0.1)
                 -----
                 -----
b.company.com >> |IIS| >> apache_server_b (10.0.0.2)
                 -----
                 -----
c.company.com >> |IIS| >> apache_server_b (10.0.0.3)
                 -----
```

But one of my apaches have 5 client sites, he use virtual host. How i can redirect the request that IIS receive for those five sites to Apache without changing the URL?

```
client1.com    -----
client2.com >> |IIS| >> apache_with_virtual_hosts (10.0.0.4)
client3.com    -----
client4.com
client5.com
```

Obs:. IIS does not stay on same machine that apache servers

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add **DNS A records** to map the subdomains name to the IP address (IPv4) of the computer with Apache hosting.
then virtual host in apache would handle the rest. as you config each subdomain.